# Typescript specify/update variable type in switch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types

I want to define const type in block in switch case

Example

```js
...

const content: undefined | number | string = apiData.content
let result
switch (apiData.type) {
    case: 1
       // update content type to only number
       result = content * 5
    break

    case: 2
       // update content type to only string
       result = content + ' is string'
    break
}

...
```

the only solution I found is to set new constant in switch blocks

```js
...

const content: undefined | number | string = apiData.content
let result
switch (apiData.type) {
    case: 1
       const newContent = content as number
       result = newContent * 5
    break

    case: 2
       const newContent = content as string
       result = newContent + ' is string'
    break
}

...
```

is there some better way to set type just for typescript something like

```js
...

const content: undefined | number | string = apiData.content
let result
switch (apiData.type) {
    case: 1
       typeof content is number // set type
       result = content * 5
    break

    case: 2
       typeof content is string // set type
       result = content + ' is string'
    break
}

...
```

real types of content are complicated interfaces but I simplified it for better understanding
in general this works automatically but not in this scenarion I have

So my only question if it is possible to update/redefine/specify const type in some block

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Because I get false errors in those areas becasue u cannot sum undefined or string for example , but real scenario is completely different with objects with different attributes defined

Answer (score 0):

`const` cannot be reassigned. [As mdn docs says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const):

> The value of a constant can't be changed through reassignment (i.e. by
> using the assignment operator), and it can't be redeclared (i.e.
> through a variable declaration).

You can use `let` instead of `const`

Comment: I don't want to reassign new value , just properly define the type in just some places of the code